# Overflow Scroll in the table with rows as dropdown

Tags: html, css, jstl

I have a table with only one row but each column is a dropdown with many option in it.

I want to have a overflow-y as scroll. I tried putting the style but its not happening.

```
<table id="DisplayTable" border="5"  RULES=ROWS FRAME=HSIDES  class='border'><tr>
                <th>value</th>
                <th>IN</th>     
                <th>OUT</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td> 
        <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 
                <option value="${user.name}">${user.name}</option><br>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       <td>
            <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 

                     <c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'IN')}">
                        <option>X</option><br>
                    </c:if>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       <td>
            <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 

                     <c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'OUT')}">
                        <option>X</option><br>
                    </c:if>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

The names can be 30-40 but I want to display only 15 on screen. rest as a scroll.
I tried with the following CSS but failed.

```
    table.border  tr th, table tr td {
        color: #008BFC;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    thead.border th {
        border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee !important;
        border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }
     #DisplayTable {
          width: 50%;
          height: 400px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. just add `<div  style="height: 400px; width: 750px; overflow-y: scroll;">` before the table.